# Azure Data Factory Labs (Collecting data from RestAPi)

Tags: data

I think that this question may have been asked previously, but this was a few years ago.

Does anybody know if Microsoft have an online lab of sorts to be able to use Azure Data Factory.

I am trying to create a POC on using this for collecting data from a 3rd party RestAPi.
We will be starting to use ADF soon and I thought it would be great if I could get some hands on experience first. So that when it comes to it, I am easily prepared.

Thanks.

Comment: Please link to the "question from a few years ago" that you mention in your first sentence, thanks!

Comment: What exact features should this "online lab" have? Please be specific.

Comment: So I was looking at the following: @NicolasRaoul (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386957/azure-data-factory-test-framework) but then I am looking at using it for collecting data from a restapi

Comment: Please detail this "collecting data from a restapi" in the question and mention it in the title, thanks! :-)